# I am having a problem where my single Ajax get call is being repeated every on every page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote logic to read the txt file on every 30 mins from Ajax script(Separate ASP) . This ASP is included on multiple ASP pages by using "Include" ..

this html code contains the below logic..

Reading the data from text file on every 30 mins and stored this data and time on local storage.
So on every page load I checked that last data reading time and compare with current time. if time > 30 mins I am reading the data again ..

But in IIS logs, call repeating on every page loads .Console log is fine ..

**foot.asp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
    let currentRequest = 0;
    $(window).on("load", function () {
        if ($(".cookiealert").hasClass('show')) {
            $("#data .popup-main").addClass("cookie-accept");
        }
        else {
            $("#data .popup-main").removeClass("cookie-accept");
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        config()
       
    });

function getData() {
        if (currentRequest == 0) {
            
            ajaxRequest = $.get({
                url: "/sample.txt",
                cache: false
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                
                if (data;) {
                   
                    addDataToStorage(data);//Adding data to localstorage
                   
                    currentRequest = 1;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("data empty");
                }
            })
            .fail(function (data, statusTxt, xhr) {
                console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            })
        }
    }
let runtimerid = null;
let exctime = "1800000";
function config() {
        let localstoragesettime, localstoragedata;
        const currentdate = new Date();
        localstoragedata = localStorage.getItem("data");
        if (localstoragedata === null || localstoragedata === "") {
            localstoragesettime = localStorage.getItem("LTime");
            if (localstoragesettime === null || localstoragesettime === "") {
                getData();
                if (runtimerid != null || runtimerid != "") {
                    clearInterval(runtimerid);
                }
                runtimerid = setTimeout(function () {
                    currentRequest = 0;
                    getData();
                }, exctime);
            }
        }
        else {
            localstoragesettime = localStorage.getItem("LTime");
            if (localstoragesettime != null || localstoragesettime != "") {
                const localstoragextime = localStorage.getItem("LTime");
                const items = JSON.parse(localstoragextime)
                epochdate = EpochToDate(items.ltime);
                differ = currentdate.getHours() - epochdate.getHours();
                if (differ > 1 || differ < 0) {
                    getData();
                    if (runtimerid != null || runtimerid != "") {
                        clearInterval(runtimerid);
                    }
                    runtimerid = setTimeout(function () {
                        currentRequest = 0;
                        getData();
                    }, exctime);
                }
                else {
                    
                    if (runtimerid != null || runtimerid != "") {
                        clearInterval(runtimerid);
                    }
                    runtimerid = setTimeout(function () {
                        currentRequest = 0;
                        getData();
                    }, exctime);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I included this foot.asp to other asp files.